# xarray autocomplete trigger computation

Tags: python, autocomplete, dask, python-xarray

When using xarray in interactive Python shell, pressing tab for autocomplete can trigger computation of values unintentionally.

MWE:

```
import dask
import dask.array
import xarray as xr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from dask.distributed import Client
    client = Client()
    print(client.dashboard_link)
    ## Test memory management of just dask.array + xr.DataArray
    da = xr.DataArray(
        data = dask.array.random.random(size=(10000,10000))
    )
    ## now type 'da.val' and press tab for autocomplete
    ## don't forget to open the dashboard first
```

How can this behaviour be avoided?

Comment: Consider using [ipython](https://pypi.org/project/ipython/)

Comment: I believe you should report this as an issue to get a code fix. The answer to your specific question would be "don't do that" :)

Comment: @mdurant Accurate answer. Now, which project should I report this issue to? Dask or xarray? I don't quite know the root cause here.

Comment: To xarray. The variable's dir method (or ipython variant, if it has it) should not be calling compute.

Comment: @mdurant Thank you, I took a look at existing reports. Found this mentioned in [related issue about __repr__ and __getattr__](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/1532#issuecomment-326632469). I guess it is already being worked on.

Comment: That issue is rather old, worth pinging or opening a new linked issue.